# Converting multiple if statements to ternary (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Given this block of statements:

```
let chosenMachine;
if (bubbleDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName)) chosenMachine = bubbleDetailsObject
if (primoDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName)) chosenMachine = primoDetailsObject
if (familyDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName)) chosenMachine = familyDetailsObject
```

How can I convert them to a one-line ternary statement?

Answer (score 2):

Without ternary statement (which might be harder to read when they're nested):

```js
const chosenMachine = [familyDetailsObject, primoDetailsObject, bubbleDetailsObject]
                      .find(o => o.names.includes(machineName));
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I'd change around the structure of your variables so that those `object`s are enclosed in *another* object or array, maybe something like:

```
const detailsObjects = {
  bubble: {
    // ...
  },
  primo: {
    // ...
```

This will both make your code more organized, but it'll also let you identify the matching object more concisely by iterating over the values, rather than having to deal with multiple similar standalone variables:

```
const chosenMachine = Object.values(detailsObjects)
  .find(obj => obj.names.includes(machineName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operations can be nested by the simple expedient of delimiting sub expressions with parentheses

```
let result = (condition 1) ? (expr 1) : (expr 2);
```

Either of the expressions can itself be a ternary expression, and the parentheses resolve all the syntactical ambiguities.

```
let result = (condition 1) ? ((condition 2) ? expr 3 : expr 4) : (expr 2);
```

However, this approach will produce code that is difficult to read and very inconvenient to debug. Even in this very simplified pseudocode the line is quite long.

Given that you are progressively testing set intersection rather than simple equality I'd be inclined to leave your original code as is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how you could do it with ternaries (granted this is not one ternary, but then your code does not contain only one `if`) , but this is not recommended for reasons that others have mentioned (i.e. lack of readability and maintainability)...

```
let chosenMachine = 
    familyDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName)
        ? familyDetailsObject
        : primoDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName)
            ? primoDetailsObject
            : bubbleDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName)
                ? bubbleDetailsObject
                : undefined;
```

Note the reverse order of `Object`s to ensure that the precedence is maintained, since any number of the `if` statements could be true.

An easier to read implementation might be something like:

```
const detailsObjects = {
    bubbleDetailsObjects: { names: ["..."] },
    primoDetailsObjects: { names: ["..."] },
    familyDetailsObjects: { names: ["..."] }
}

let chosenMachine; 

Object.keys(detailsObjects).forEach(key => {
    chosenMachine = 
        detailsObjects[key].names.includes(machineName)
            ? machineName
            : chosenMachine;
})
```

This gives you a single ternary statement while also preserving your original objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ternaries are supposed to return a single value, In your code the 3 if's can be `true` when `machineName` exists inside the three objects, assuming thats unintended, your ternary should look like this:

```
const chosenMachine = bubbleDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName) ? bubbleDetailsObject : primoDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName) ? primoDetailsObject : familyDetailsObject.names.includes(machineName) ? familyDetailsObject : null;
```